# Android instant app deeplink with custom scheme: UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have an SDK that registers an Activity to handle a custom scheme, at some point the SDK would open a http url to my website, upon clicking a button in the website, a user will be redirect to `customscheme://scheme_host_url/their_application_id` - which would close the browser and redirect back to the user's native app using the SDK by opening `CustomSchemeHandlingActivity`

However if an **instant app** uses my SDK, this would not work, they will just see `net:UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` in their browser. I think this is expected, as instant app doesn't really have my SDK and `CustomSchemeHandlingActivity` installed locally.

Is it expected that this just won't work for Android instant app?

```
<activity
    android:name=".CustomSchemeHandlingActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        ...
        <data
            android:scheme="customscheme"
            android:host="scheme_host_url"
            android:path="/${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instant Apps only work with App Links, and as you already know this means that you can only use `https` urls.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/instant-app-links